# error: one of src or dest must be a remote file specification

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to move local folder into kubernetes volume by following command:

```
kubectl cp /* mynamespace/mypod-xxxx-xxxx:/var/www/my-content
```

Unfortunately, I got following error message:

> error: one of src or dest must be a remote file specification

even I've configured volume mount as follow:

```
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/var/www/my-content"
          name: mycontent
  volumes:
    - name: mycontent
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: mypvc
```

Please let me know which I missed something to configure it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an issue in `*` which is not currently supported by kubectl cp.
To solve this issue just remove * and use the full directory name like

```
kubectl cp /folder_name/ mynamespace/mypod-xxxx-xxxx:/var/www/my-content
```

but in this case a folder will be created  like  `/var/www/my-content/folder_name`.
you have to adjust this in your code or you can name your local folder name like my-content and copy to `/var/www/`.